# can't find css file in theme editor

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, elementor

[image]
I wanna highlight the menu label yellow when i am on that page but it turns black and therefore can't be seen on the navbar. I am searching for post-25875.css to edit but cannot locate it in the theme editor as well nor is it changing using additional css tab. Can someone tell me where is it located or how can i edit this css rule?

Comment: From the screenshot this is an Elementor element , You can use the elementor wysiwig editor inside wordpress to edit this wordpress page or post to change the style of this elementor Element. The linked CSS should be an Elementor CSS which should be based on bootstrap or foundation since its a responsive menu. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "post-25875" and you will see where is the file.

Because of the "!important" this style take priority.
You can try to add a more accurate selector before and keep the "!important".

```
#YOUR-SELECTOR .elementor-27875 [.copy the all selector.] .aux-menu-label{
    color: blue !important;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: To find where the original CSS is located, you can open up any random Elementor page, then inside the URL change the ID of the page to "27875", and it'll open the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a paid theme? I think you are using paid theme .if yes you can change the styles and fonts everything from the admin dashboard. which theme is using?

Comment: It is a Phlox theme. I am using a free version. I got the file along with the custom CSS tab which i used for editing.